# Can someone explain me how do i get 0.250. how does the math work in this?

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tniri.png)

Is there a rule when you divide that the + becomes - or something like that, because i dont get it how does it print 0.250

Comment: Post the code as text in the question.

Comment: https://www.autodraw.com/share/IT1MN5NM2W3N

Comment: `1/2` is `0` - don't do integer math if you want `float` results

Comment: In your own words, when you wrote `1/4.0`, why did you write that, rather than writing `1/4`? Do you see why the same issue applies to writing `1/2` rather than `1/2.0`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) It is also a good idea to make sure you understand the fundamentals of the language you are learning: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial resource.

Comment: its from a test I did not write this code, that's why I am little bit confused

Answer (score 0):

`1/2` 1 and 2 both are integers so they evaluates to `0`
beacuse of this `x= 0 + 0.250` gives the result `0.250`